# Solve complex system of equations for mixed real and complex unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-complexity

I have a system of $M$ complex equations

$$ \sum_{j=1}^N ( a_{ij} \ x_j + c_{ij} \ y_j)= b_i $$

where $i \in [1, M]$ and $a_{ij}, x_j, c_{ij}, b_i \in \mathbb{C}$ but $y_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to solve for unknown $x_j, y_j$.  Assuming $M = \frac{3}{2}N$ I have as many equations as I have unknowns and I could break the equations out in to their real and imaginary parts and put them in a big real matrix and solve using real matrix techniques.  But I lose the performance advantage of using complex matrix techniques.

Is there a way to solve for the unknowns without reverting to the equivalent real and imaginary equations?

Comment: What real matrix technique are you considering that does not have a complex equivalent? If you propose an approach, someone may be able to give a comparable complex algorithm.

Comment: @Dunham Just normal LU decomposition.  There's of course a complex equivalent, but it's not obvious what to do about the unknown variables which are real.  If we treat them as complex we A) don't have enough equations and B) have an extra imaginary component that we don't want on those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing response from a couple of years ago.  Sure
you can put in block form and just take advantage of
complex arithmetic,  but thought more about problem.
The performance advantage is when there are many fewer real variables than complex variables.  Don't know if worthwhile otherwise.

Prefer to use z for complex,  and $\lambda$ for real.
If you can put in the form
\begin{equation}
A z  + B \lambda = u
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ complex,  and $u$ are complex.
It is assumed that the matrix $A$ is invertible.   The second block  equation has a complex matrix $C$,  a real matrix $D$,  and a real valued right hand side $v$:
\begin{equation}
Re(C z) + D \lambda = v.
\label{eq:realeq}
\end{equation}
Where $Re$ takes the real part of a complex expression. We use the Hadamard product, $\odot$, to apply the $Re$ function to the lower equation.  The Hadamard product is used with lower precedence than the matrix multiplication. It is not defined if you try to do in the other order as the matrices are not of equal size.

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
Re \\
\end{bmatrix}
\odot
\begin{bmatrix}
&A ~~& B \\
&C~~& D \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z \\
\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
v \\
\end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:prob}
\end{equation}

Then you can follow through the derivation for use of Schur complement
\begin{equation}
S \equiv D- \left(CA^{-1}B \right)
\label{eq:sdef}
\end{equation}
to get. (See the section "Application to solving linear equations" of the wiki page for Schur complement)

\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix}
z \\
\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{p} &-A^{-1}B \\
& I_{q}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} \\
&\left(  Re \left( S \right) \right)^{-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
f\\
g \\
\end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:inv}
\end{equation}
Where the single column matrix with  complex $f$ and real $g$ are calculated by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
f\\
g \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
Re \\
\end{bmatrix}
\odot
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{p}\\
-C A^{-1} &I_{q} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
v\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Note that it is more efficient to calculate
\begin{equation}
Re(CA^{-1}B) =  Re(C) Re(A^{-1}B) -  Im(C) Im(A^{-1} B)
\end{equation}
so we are better off storing $C$ as two real matrices.

Remember you can factor out reals from the real function, but
not complex values.  For example,  $Re \left(C A^{-1} B \lambda \right) = Re \left( C A^{-1} B \right) \lambda$. It is linear over the reals,   that is why you can factor out the Schur complement. But the real function is not linear over the complex field.
Try comparing $i \cdot Re(i)$, $ Re(i \cdot i) $ and $ Re(i)Re(i)$.

In the case I was working on,
$B$ and $C$ are conjugate transposes. All the entries to the matrix $D$ and the $u$ vector are 0.  For this case,   simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
 z = A^{-1} B \left[ Re(B^{H} A^{-1} B) \right]^{-1} v,
\end{equation}
where we have used the superscript H to indicate the conjugate transpose.
See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4884759/1060562